# Atom failed install packages

Tags: atom-editor

If I install any packages I get error log below. Some packages were going to install. Do´t you know how to fix it?

```
C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9
`-- (empty)


npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\Roman\.atom\.apm\jquery\2.1.4\package.tgz
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9 No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9 No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9 No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.19.3\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.19.3\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "C:\\Users\\Roman\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\Roman\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d-117728-8144-m4vd0u.pvq54p9zfr\\package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.6.9" "--arch=x64" "--global-style" "--msvs_version=2015"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9\node_modules\.staging\jquery-c839d795\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9\node_modules\.staging\jquery-c839d795\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9\node_modules\.staging\jquery-c839d795\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-117728-8144-tjhcy5.164lkutyb9\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: What were you trying to install?

Comment: I've got the same error let me know if you found a solution. I also found [this issue](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/669)

Comment: Yes i have solution. Just remove folder jquery and try again install package.